# Is there a way to query munin about system performance?

Tags: ruby, monitoring

Basically I would just like to run a script that queries munin for certain stats periodically instead of getting alerts or checking a graph page.  Some sort of ruby lib for getting perf info would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the RRD files munin generates with rrdtool -- it parses them into XML.